# Python Kivy _PyGen_Send

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.10

При попытке запустить код с использованием фреймворка Kivy на Python 3.10, выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/milvus/startapp/main.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/uix/boxlayout.py", line 77, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.layout import Layout
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 59, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 239, in <module>
     from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/event.py", line 8, in <module>
     import kivy._event
 ImportError: /usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/kivy/_event.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _PyGen_Send
```

На предыдущей версии Python такой проблемы не возникало, перерыл все что можно, решение не нашел, пните меня куда надо или помогите решить вроблему

Comment: Значит kivy еще не обновили под 3.10, используйте более старую версию. Альтернативный вариант, если так уж нужна версия 3.10 - написать автору kivy issue на гитхабе (если такого еще нет).